# Windows service connects to a server to download some files

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, accessibility, directory

*There are three serves on the same zone. 172.*.*.**

**Suppose that their names  are A,B and C**

The server A has a windows service, and it downloads the files from the server of C, in the folder of images. It used to give errors about access-denied then we assign full control to everyone on the folder of images on the server C. Then it was ok.

Now the same windows service runs on the server B, and ,t gets the same things from images folder of the server C. But there is an error about access-denied.

What should I do for the required steps to make the server B be able to connect the server C and download the files? Please step-by-step...

***The error:  Exception:Access to the path '\172.*.*.*\images' is denied.*

**\172.*.*.*\ aka the server C***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create service accounts in you Active Directoy to allow there service run under a user account rather than network service or local computer.

You will then need to make a change to the Local Security policy to allow that user run as service

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Local Security Policy\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Log on as Service\

Add the user account to the share security with the apropriate rights on servers B and C

Hope this helps

Iain

Comment: @ I tried to add the Computer on to the "Log on as Service" but it did not work.

Comment: as mentioned above create a user account / not use the computer account, you also try adding SERVER$ as user permission on B and C for each computer